# Show button/Play Message when all draggable elements are dropped. Adobe Edge Animate Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to create a drag and drop interaction using Adobe Edge Animate of which primarily runs on Jquery and Javascript.

Everything is draggable and droppable as I wish, however, I need the code to recognize and count when the correct element is dropped on the correct target, when all 15 elements are dropped correctly I want a message to play (in which a button will be made visible).

**To break it down:**
Count when element_1 is dropped on target_1, when elements 1-15 have been dropped correctly, sym.play('ButtonLabel - that will make a button visible).

**The code I am currently using is below:**

```
yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui.min.js'], complete: init});

function init(){
    //Drag
    sym.$('Designed').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Interactive').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Evaluated').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Raised').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Clear').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Created').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Fundraising').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Communicated').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('LongLasting').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Saved').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Increased').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Organisations').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Organised').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('Achieving').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

sym.$('IncreasedConfidence').draggable({ 
    opacity: 0.5,
    revert: 'invalid',
});

//Drop
sym.$('DesignedTarget').droppable({
    accept: sym.$('Designed'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Designed").play();
}
});

sym.$('EvaluatedTarget').droppable({
    accept: sym.$('Evaluated'), 
            drop: function() {
                sym.getSymbol("Evaluated").play();
            }
});

sym.$('CreatedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Created'),    
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Created").play();
}});

sym.$('CommunicatedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Communicated'),   
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Communicated").play();
}});

sym.$('OrganisedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Organised'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Organised").play();
}});

sym.$('InteractiveTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Interactive'),    
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Interactive").play();
}});

sym.$('FundraisingTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Fundraising'),    
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Fundraising").play();
}});

sym.$('OrganisationsTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Organisations'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Organisations").play();
}});

sym.$('LongLastingTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('LongLasting'),    
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("LongLasting").play();
}});

sym.$('ClearTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Clear'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Clear").play();
}});

sym.$('RaisedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Raised'), 
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Raised").play();
}});

sym.$('SavedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Saved'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Saved").play();
}});

sym.$('IncreasedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Increased'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Increased").play();
}});

sym.$('AchievingTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Achieving'),  
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("Achieving").play();
}});

sym.$('IncreasedConfidenceTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('IncreasedConfidence'),    
    drop: function() {
        sym.getSymbol("IncreasedConfidence").play();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a variable that just iterates whenever a item is droped in the drop: function. Once the Counter reaches 15 it should just execute the play.

```
$counter = 0;
....
sym.$('SavedTarget').droppable({
   accept: sym.$('Saved'),  
    drop: function() {
        $counter += 1;
        sym.getSymbol("Saved").play();
}});
....
if($counter == 15) {
   sym.play('ButtonLabel');
}
```

Comment: It did not work, unfortunately! Will try to upload it to site and see if the Edge Animate program is blocking the code.